# visibility of custom objects in managed package

Tags: managed-package, beta-managed-package

I want to add a custom object in my managed package.
And i want that content of that custom object will be 
visible to only admins of org installing the package.
how to achieve this?

Scenario is i want to make webservice call out from sfdc , and want to validate users in my webservice which is called by sfdc
i.e. salesforce org will register for my webservice first , while registration i will store the credentials in a custom object in their sfdc org in encrypted form
and later when sfdc will call the webservice it will pass the credentials in encrypted form , and my webservice will validate them first and then only will give response
please help me out in this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can apply object level security to System Administrator profile, In which you need to restrict all profiles except Administrator in organization.

Also when you install that package in other org than matching profile permissions will apply on target org profiles. During installation System administrator has provided option of 'Grant access to admins only' or 'Grant access to all users'. I think you have to manually provide permission to objects.

In package only Tab settings, page layout and recordType are determined by package creator. To give more privileges you can use permission sets then.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good use case for a [Protected Custom Setting](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_customsettings.htm). Protected Custom Settings are not visible to any users in the Target Org. But you can make some or all of the fields visible/editable via a Visualforce page included in your package.

I use this for the purpose you describe. I include a Tab/VF page with a button that lets a customer create a trial/subscription, which submits their info  to my webservice and I can create an authentication key, pass it back to their org and store it in their custom setting. BUt because I never make the Auth Key field visible via the VF page, they can never see it, but it is then included in each subsequent callout to my webservice.